# DataAdapter Fill without command

Tags: c#, sql, dataset, dataadapter

I'm trying to fill my dataadapter without using a command. I have a dataset which I manually populated but when I try to attach this dataset with my dataAdapter I'm gettin "The Select command property has not been initialized before calling 'Fill'". This is my code does anyone has an idea for this ?

Thanks

```
OleDbDataAdapter ad1=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
OleDbDataAdapter ad2=new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd2);
OleDbDataAdapter ad3 = new OleDbDataAdapter();

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable db1=new DataTable();
DataTable db2=new DataTable();
DataTable db3 = new DataTable();
ds.Tables.Add();

ad1.Fill(db1);
ad2.Fill(db2);
int i;
foreach (DataRow r in db2.Rows)
{
    i = 0;
    foreach (DataRow rc in db1.Rows)
    {
        if (r[0].ToString() == rc[0].ToString())
        {
            i = 1;
        }
    }
    if (i == 0) { ds.Tables[0].ImportRow(r); }

}
ad3.Fill(ds);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish here, it is unclear from your description.  You already have placed data in the DataSet with:

```
    ds.Tables[0].ImportRow(r);
```

Also, a Data Adapter of any type has to have at the very least a SELECT command associated in order for it to fill a Data Table or Data Set.

Could you describe your objective a bit more clearly?  Are you trying to add a table to the dataset?  Fill it from some external source?  View the rows you imported?

Comment: actually I just want to fill my datagridview with my manually filled dataset but when i try that it shows empty

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.  You already have a table in the dataset so you just need to set your datagridview's datasource to that table. Try myDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];  That will show you the rows you imported to the table.

Comment: Jas, did this work for you?  If so please mark the question answered.  Thanks!